# Python Beautiful Soup parse a table with a specific ID

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the data from a table with a specific ID which I know.
For some reason, the code keeps giving me a None result.

From the HTML code I'm trying to parse:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="gridHeader" valign="top">
        <td class="titleGridRegNoB" align="center" valign="top"><span dir=RTL>שווי שוק (אלפי ש"ח)</span></td>
        <td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">הון רשום למסחר</td>
        <td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער נמוך</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער גבוה</td>
        <td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער בסיס</td>
        <td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער פתיחה</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top"><span dir="rtl">שער נעילה (באגורות)</span></td>
        <td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער נעילה מתואם</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">תאריך</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#FDF1D7'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'">
```

... And so on

My code:

```
html = br.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and tag.has_key('id') and tag['id']=="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1")
rows = table.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr')

In [100]: print table
None
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `find_all(tag, id="id_name")`?

Comment: You're talking about the rows creation? Unfortunately the table itself is empty, so it doesn't matter.. I need the get the "table" done right first..

Comment: It's the same thing with this line `table = soup.find()`

Comment: @aIKid `table = soup.find(tag, id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1")`

gives: 
`NameError: name 'tag' is not defined`

Comment: Does that work? I've added an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find):

```
table = soup.find('table', id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1")
```

And the for the rows line:

```
rows = table.findAll('tr')
```

For the encoding problem, try decoding it from `utf-8`, and re-encode it.

```
html = br.response().read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: @alKid thanks for helping, but it still returns None:
`table = soup.find('table', id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1")

print table
None`

Could it be because it's a table inside a table ?

Comment: @aIKid But the problem is this, he's using UTF-8, so this might be a problem to work with. There's hebrew in his html.

Comment: please save response from mechanize browser br.  f=open('test.html','w');html = br.response().read();f.write(html), and check the saved page. May be you are getting a non valid response :)

Comment: How to find a table if I don't have `id`, but  a `class`?

Answer (score 1):

Improving upon aiKid's answer:

```
# coding=utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = u"""
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <tr class="gridHeader" valign="top">
                                <td class="titleGridRegNoB" align="center" valign="top"><span dir=RTL>שווי שוק (אלפי ש"ח)</span></td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">הון רשום למסחר</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער נמוך</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער גבוה</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער בסיס</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער פתיחה</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top"><span dir="rtl">שער נעילה (באגורות)</span>
</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער נעילה מתואם</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">תאריך</td>
                            </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#FDF1D7'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'">
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find_all("table",
                    id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1")
```

Since you're working with UTF-8 data, you need to set the string as a unicode string like so `u"""(...)"""`. All you need to do to work with unicode is this:

```
br.response().read().decode('utf-8')
```

The above will give you an ASCII string, that you can later encode into unicode. Like, say the string is stored in `html`, and you can encode it back to unicode using `html.encode("utf-8")`. If you do this, you do not need to put the `u` in front of anything. You can treat everything as a regular string again.

Comment: Try wrapping it unicode, like so `html = unicide(br.response(),read())`

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried:
`table_id = u"""ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1"""
table = soup.findall(u"""table""", id=table_id)`

And I get: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: @erantdo have you tried using his recommendation? Changin this line: `html = unicode(br.response(),read())`

Comment: @erantdo Well, the ID does not have an unicode in it so no problem. Did you make sure to put in a `# encoding=utf-8` at the very top of the file?

Comment: @alKid @Gamesbrainiac I added this on top but it's a comment (I'm using Canopy). also, changing to `html = unicode(br.response().read())` returns `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 118: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Thanks. Snippet #24499

Comment: @erantdo link please.

Comment: @erantdo I've updated my answer too. Tested it with a file and works fine. :)

Comment: @alKid thanks, but now I'm getting: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` for the line `table = soup.findall("table", id=table_id)`

Comment: @erantdo I see now, you need to decode it first, you're using a psuedo browser called mechanize.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac @alKid Thanks, but I changed the code to https://dpaste.de/fWDa and now I'm getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: @erantdo Ask a separate question then, this convo is getting too long.

Comment: Can you do that, @Games ?

Comment: @aIKid Not yet. But what he's asking about is mechanize, and thats a separate question altogether, and needs to create a separate topic.

Comment: @alKid Thanks a lot guys. New topic is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593340/python-beautiful-soup-parsing-a-utf-8-coded-table-using-mechanize