# Python Beautiful Soup parsing a UTF-8 coded table (using mechanize)

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, mechanize-python

I'm trying to parse the following table, coded in UTF-8 (this is part of it):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <tr class="gridHeader" valign="top">
                                <td class="titleGridRegNoB" align="center" valign="top"><span dir=RTL>שווי שוק (אלפי ש"ח)</span></td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">הון רשום למסחר</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער נמוך</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער גבוה</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער בסיס</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער פתיחה</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top"><span dir="rtl">שער נעילה (באגורות)</span>    
</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">שער נעילה מתואם</td><td class="titleGridReg" align="center" valign="top">תאריך</td>
                            </tr><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#FDF1D7'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'">
```

My code is:

```
html = br.response().read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table_id = "ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1"
table = soup.findall("table", id=table_id)
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hey, can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Current code is at: https://dpaste.de/w6cV

Comment: @alKid I'm sorry, but what do you mean by full traceback?

Comment: All the full traceback. Or.. is that the only thing that popped out when executing the script?

Comment: @alKid yep. The problematic line is `table = soup.findall("table", id=table_id)`. I changed it to `table = soup.find(id=table_id)` according to @GamesBrainiac and now it returns `None`

Comment: @erantdo We can't get access to that, url for some reason. Atleast I can't.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac https://dpaste.de/Nb4b -I created a new one, does that help?

Comment: I'm getting access denied. I get a `You don't have permission to access "http://www.tase.co.il/Heb/General/Company/Pages/companyHistoryData.aspx?" on this server.`

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Ohh, you meant the TAES url. Will it help if I paste the HTML source in dpaste.de ?

Comment: @erantdo Well no, because thats what you just did, right?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac here it is: https://dpaste.de/EWCK - and in case I forgot - thank you so much for trying to help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just finding using an `id`, you can just use `id` and nothing else, because `id`s are unique:

### UPDATE

Using your paste:

```
# encoding=utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = requests.get('https://dpaste.de/EWCK/raw/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
print soup.find("table",
                id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c001c0d9_0cb8_4b0f_b75a_7cc3b6f7d790_ctl00_HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1")
```

I'm using python requests to get the data from a webpage, its same as as you trying to get the data. The above code works, and the correct ID is given. Try this for a change, don't use `.decode('utf-8')`, instead, just use `br.response().read()`.

Comment: Thanks, but now it returns `None`

Comment: @erantdo Thats strange, it works fine on my computer, is it because you're using canopy? Try running this with just normal python.

Comment: @aIKid How does it not?

Comment: @erantdo I think I know where the problem is, when you encode it into ASCII, what happens is that you get lots of slashes. This messes up BeautifulSoup's parsing.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I don't understand. I removed the `.decode` and it's it's still returns `None`. If you're telling me to use `requests` then I have a problem with that - that's why I'm using `mechanize`

Comment: Use mechanize, keep everything as is, just remove the decode part.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I'm sorry, but it returns `None`... code is at: https://dpaste.de/DrdD

Comment: @erantdo Then I'm really out of ideas, since I don't have access to your side, so I can't see anything for myself.