# Python BeautifulSoup cannot find table ID

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am running into some trouble scraping a table using BeautifulSoup. Here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/clemson/2014.html"
page = urlopen(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")

stats = soup.find('table',  id = 'totals')

In [78]: print(stats)
None
```

When I right click on the table to inspect the element the HTML looks as I'd expect, however when I view the source the only element with id = 'totals' is commented out. Is there a way to scrape a table from the commented source code?

I have referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591720/python-beautiful-soup-parse-a-table-with-a-specific-id) but can't seem to replicate their solution.

Here is a [link to the webpage](http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/clemson/2014.html) I am interested in. I'd like to scrape the table labeled "Totals" and store it as a data frame.

I am relatively new to Python, HTML, and web scraping. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Comment: Please update your answer to include the relevant parts of the HTML source you're trying to scrape from. We need the question to be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments are string instances in BeautifulSoup.  You can use BeautifulSoup's find method with a regular expression to find the particular string that you're after.  Once you have the string, have BeautifulSoup parse that and there you go.

In other words,

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/clemson/2014.html"
page = urlopen(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")

stats_html = soup.find(string=re.compile('id="totals"'))
stats_soup = BeautifulSoup(stats_html, "html.parser")

print(stats_soup.table.caption.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
from urllib2 import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/clemson/2014.html"
page = urlopen(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")

stats = soup.findAll('div', id = 'all_totals')
print stats
```

Please inform me if I helped!

Comment: Your answer doesn't get access to the div with the id=totals.  It gets the one with id=all_totals.  Embedded within there is the div he's after, but it's still a comment and as a comment is pretty much unusable. Try actually printing just the div he's after with your solution.  You'll need to work with comments to get what's asked for in this question.